# Communication between Main Function and States

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, communication

I consider to build a game engine with the following design approach.

The principal characteristic is to create so called systems, which cover game menus and game levels. These systems are provided with objects like `Window` to draw, `Input` to fetch, `Sound` to play, and maybe `Network` to communicate with a server.

```
class System // abstract class
{
     Window* Window;
     Input* Input;
     ...

     System(Window* Window, Input* Input, ...)
     {
          this->Window = Window;
          this->Input= Input;
          ...
     }

     virtual Pause() = 0;
     virtual Resume() = 0;
}
```

The main function handles the systems thus menus and levels. Say `LevelOne` is derived from `System`.

```
int main()
{
     LevelOne Tutorial(&Window, &Input, ...); 
     Tutorial.Pause();
     ...
}
```

This way my code becomes structured and (in my opinion) easy to understand. But how could the main function communicate with the systems?

For example, how could the menu tell the main function that the user had selected a level, and which one? In order to let the main function delete the menu and create a new level object.

Comment: Remark 1: This look like Java/C# code, are you sure you got the language tag right ?

Comment: I write my game engine in C++ and OpenGL. But in the last years I used C# a lot, so I made a mistake. I will change the dots to `->`.

Comment: This is, actually, the lesser mistake. In Java and C# you only ever manipulate references to objects, however in C++ you choose whether to manipulate values or references/pointers. And unless there is a good reason to, you should be using values, and not write a `new`. You first need to refamiliriaze yourself with C++ before you can tackle building a game engine.

Comment: Sorry to insist but... not yet. It would be simpler if you were storing values in `System`, and got rid of that destructor and the `delete` (if you need to write `delete` in C++, you're doing it wrong, there are smart pointers for this).

Comment: You are right, the `delete`s are wrong. But I don't want to store the values in `System` because I want to use the same sound/input/... object in all of the systems. That's why I use pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do here is organize a complete model-view-controller architecture, and the code you provided here is the model and controller portion of it.  See some explanations on MVC on the web:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html

If you have a single main() function trying to listen for messages from your subsystems and calling the appropriate actions as a result, you are trying to implement a single-threaded reactive message loop.  You could consider running an ACE reactor that can listen for Qt GUI messages as well as others such as network events, then call your subsystems appropriately (though there may be some performance issues):

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-rules.pdf

I am not familiar with graphics engines for video game programming, but most graphics libraries offer a message loop for you during its initialization that doesn't require you to go through this kind of detail.  All you typically have to do is create your graphics objects and register them with the main message loop of the library.

And I would recommend using a separate thread listening for network events compared to your message thread listening for graphics events.  It separates the work out and helps to improve the performance of your graphics.

Comment: As a web developer I understand MVC, at least in a web application context. I am not sure if this approach would be necessary and beneficial for solving my problem. It is only about game states like menus and levels. I will use a MVC and a Event approach ingame but that's another thing. Can you give me an advice for implementing your idea?

Comment: The model in this case is the state of your menus or the state of the tutorial or game.  The view is the actual graphics themselves.  The controller would be your message loop and the handler objects to which you dispatch your events to.  

If you are using the ACE reactor, you would create an ACE_Acceptor for each of your subsystems, subclass them from the ACE_Svc_Handler,  and implement a handle_input() function to "react" to the events that are coming in.

If your graphics are not natively supported in ACE, you'll have to use a different controller that can be supported.